subtraction of numpy arrays with different dimensions
print(np.array([1,2])-np.array([[1,1]]))

I am getting output of the following code as [[0,1]]. can anyone tell me why?

What did you you expect instead?

Your (2,) broadcasts with (1,2), yielding (1,2)

The output is as expected from standard Numpy behavior: You have a 1D Numpy array of 2 elements ([1,2]), and you are subtracting a 2D Numpy array of 1×2 elements ([[1,1]]) from it.*
Numpy behaves as follows here :

Arrays are usually subtracted elementwise (see basic and detailed documentation). In your case, this means 1-1=0 (values at index 0) and 2-1=1 (values at index 1).
If array shapes differ but are compatible, broadcasting comes into play (see basic and detailed documentation). In your case, this has the effect that (a) values along the last dimension of both arrays are subtracted elementwise (as described above) and (b) the result has the same shape as the input array with most dimensions (so 1×2 elements).

As a result, we end up with the 2D Numpy array of 1×2 elements that you observed: [[0,1]].
*) How do you know that the 1st array is 1D and that the 2nd array is 2D? The 1st has a single pair of square brackets ([…]), while the 2nd has a double pair of square brackets ([[…]]).
